# passing value to textbox

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I'm working on project. I want to pass value of `textbox1` to `form 1` and `form 3`, but it passes value only to that form which comes first(here `form1`).

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >

   submitForms = function() {
var answer = document.getElementById("textbox1").value;
var q = document.getElementById('q');
q.value = answer;
var q1 = document.getElementById('q1');
q1.value=answer;
document.forms["form1"].submit();
document.forms["form3"].submit();
  }

< /script>
```

```html
<body background="a.jpg">
  <p>
    </br>

    <input type="text" name="textbox1" id="textbox1" style="width:600px;height:30px;border:3px solid white" placeholder="Search..." required/>
    <input type="submit" name="button1" id="button1" value="go" style="width:50px;height:30px;color:black;background-color:white" onclick="submitForms()" />

    </br>
    </br>

    <iframe width="100%" height="500px" name="myIframe" frameborder='0'></iframe>
    <iframe width="100%" height="1700px" name="myIframe1" frameBorder="0"></iframe>

    <form method="get" action="http://bing.com//search" target="myIframe1" name="form1">
      <input type="text" name="q" id="q" size="25" maxlength="255" value="" style="display: none" />
    </form>

    <form method="get" action="http://duckduckgo.com/" target="myIframe" name="form3">
      <input type="text" name="q1" id="q1" size="25" maxlength="255" value="" style="display: none" />
    </form>


  </p>
</body>
```

Comment: add var q1 = document.getElementById('q1');
    q1.value = answer; & check.

Comment: include var q1 = document.getElementById('q1'); q1.value=answer;

Comment: sorry i posted wrong code

Comment: still it is not working

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
var q1 = document.getElementById('q1');
q1.value=answer;
```

you forgot to fill the 2 forms.

Answer (score 0):

Forgot another id q1
`

```
<script type = "text/javascript">

  submitForms = function() {
    var answer = document.getElementById("textbox1").value;
    var q = document.getElementById('q');
    var qq = document.getElementById('q1');
    q.value = answer;
    qq.value = answer;
    document.forms["form1"].submit();
    document.forms["form3"].submit();

  }

</script>
```